# Check if it clicked when other element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Lets say I have `divB` inside `divA`. I have a click event on `divA`.
But how to check if `divB` inside `divA` is also clicked?

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zwxK6/

The Script -

```
$('#divA').on('click', function() {
    //What to do here? how to check if divB inside divA is clicked also?
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#divA').on('click', function() {
    alert('divA is clicked');
});

$('#divB').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('divB is clicked');
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zwxK6/3/)

Answer (score 4):

Use event object to get the source of event, pass event object to function you are binding for click, `event.target` will give you source of event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/zwxK6/1/)**

```
$('#divA').on('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
    //Use event.target.id to check if divB inside divA is clicked also
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

This will click the `divA` and then `divB` get clicked too.

You can find like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zwxK6/4/

```
function fireIt(id) {
    alert(id + " is clicked too.");
}
$(function() {
    $('#divA').on('click', function(e) {
       $(e.target.id).children('div').click(
          fireIt($(e.target).children('div').attr('id'))
       );
    });
});
```